# syntax error on javascript api. how can i fix it

Tags: javascript

> pls i dont know why this syntax error i change colone but doesn't work

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
'method': 'GET',
'url' : '"https://openapi.botnoi.ai/botnoi/ecommerce?keyword=undefined"'
headers : {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MTIwOTM5MjcsImlkIjoiNTJjYTJjODgtNDI2Ny00ZDEwLTkwNzktYmE4MGMxZWNhMzQ5IiwiaXNzIjoiZnloRHFJV1Npb3R4YmN3MkI4amZ5dUJBdUNHdFRLcm4iLCJuYW1lIjoiMTQzMy4wOCIsInBpYyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcHJvZmlsZS5saW5lLXNjZG4ubmV0LzBoR1diUjVwYTVHSGhmS3pCcDdReG5MMk51RmhVb0JSNHdKMGxXR0h3dlFFMTJIVjRvWVJoVlNuOV9RMHh4SFZncE1VNEhHM3A1UWgxdyJ9.wfEGlqTBL1YQMsKWOEunptFk3mudSINF0ohdjTraCD0'
}
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
if (error) throw new Error(error);)
console.log(response.body);
});
```

Comment: At first glance you are missing a coma between url and headers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a comma after your `url` property. Also remove the closing bracket after your  `throw new Error`. These are extremely minor mistakes.

```js
var request = require('request');
var options = {
'method': 'GET',
'url' : '"https://openapi.botnoi.ai/botnoi/ecommerce?keyword=undefined"',
headers : {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MTIwOTM5MjcsImlkIjoiNTJjYTJjODgtNDI2Ny00ZDEwLTkwNzktYmE4MGMxZWNhMzQ5IiwiaXNzIjoiZnloRHFJV1Npb3R4YmN3MkI4amZ5dUJBdUNHdFRLcm4iLCJuYW1lIjoiMTQzMy4wOCIsInBpYyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcHJvZmlsZS5saW5lLXNjZG4ubmV0LzBoR1diUjVwYTVHSGhmS3pCcDdReG5MMk51RmhVb0JSNHdKMGxXR0h3dlFFMTJIVjRvWVJoVlNuOV9RMHh4SFZncE1VNEhHM3A1UWgxdyJ9.wfEGlqTBL1YQMsKWOEunptFk3mudSINF0ohdjTraCD0'
}
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
if (error) throw new Error(error);
console.log(response.body);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. 
i have a bit question
why header arent change to 'headers'